# Navigation between storyboards - Entering in different sequence

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have the following layout, each of the screens you can see on the image is a storyboard.

[image: Storyboard layout]

One of the issues I have is, in my AppDeligate file I have a redirect based on a var value.

If I redirect from the AppDeligate to any page but the first in the image above, none of the navigations work.

I am using the following code to navigate between my storyboards

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "welcome")
self.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

And the following code to hide the navigation on particular pages:-

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
```

Why does the navigation disappear when I enter at any page but the first in the sequence.
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Why the downvotes without leaving a comment as to why?
If this seems so simple you have to downvote why not just answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use other vc, you present a UIViewController only, not a UINavigationController, then no exist a navigation that show.

You need to check if your vc is the first and it's not use a navigationController.

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds) 
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) 
var initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "welcome") 

if !(initialViewController is UINavigationController) {

    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: initialViewController)

    initialViewController = navigationController
}

self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: I get the following error when I attempt to add this code:-  Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'present'

Comment: I just used your code. How you "redirect from the AppDelegate"?

Comment: Sorry, I pull that code from another view here is the code:-

            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            
            let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "welcome")
            
            self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

Comment: I forgot to comment, @TonyHensler I edited my answer.